# Next js error when linking to a dynamic page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following structure:

```
- blog (directory)
-- index.js (list of all blog articles)
-- [slug].js (single article)
```

when I am inside `index.js` I have:

```
const Blog = props => {
  const { pageProps: { articles } } = props
  const blogArticles = objectToArray(articles)

  return (
    <Layout bio={props.bio}>
      <Title>
        I am excited by the idea of sharing my knowledge and perhaps inspiring others.
      </Title>
      {blogArticles.map(
        (article, i) => <Card key={`id-${i}`} data={article} />
      )}
    </Layout>
  )
}

Blog.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const articles = await getBlogArticles()
  return { articles }
}
```

and the card component has the link:

```
...
    <Link href={`/blog/${slug}`}>
      <Wrapper>
        <ImgWrapper>
          <Img src={BASE_URL + url} />
        </ImgWrapper>
        <TextWrapper>
          <Title>{title}</Title>
          <ArtcilePreview>{intro}</ArtcilePreview>
        </TextWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
    </Link>
...
```

and inside `[slug].js` I have:

```
const BlogArticle = (props) => {
  return (
    <Layout bio={props.bio}>
      <Article title={props.pageProps.article[0].title} content={props.pageProps.article[0].content} />
      <ArticleShare url={'process.env.API_URL + asPath'} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

BlogArticle.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const article = await getArticleBySlug(query.slug)
  return { article }
}
```

when I click within the card component to go to the dynamically generated page, it works correctly. However, during the transition from `url/blog` to `url/blog/my-slug` I can see an error message appearing and disappearing quickly in the console.
It looks like it cannot find the page that is dynamically generated throwing what I think to be a `500 error`.

I cannot figure out why it appears and disappears so quickly.

ERROR BELOW I HAVE RECORDED A SCREEN VIDEO

[image]

Comment: can you try throttling your internet connection through devtools and see the error before page reloads ?

Comment: @nikoss image uploaded. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction#linking-between-pages) you should not add the actual slug in `href`
If you check the docs of Link I linked above correct usage is

```
<Link href="/blog/[slug]" as={`/blog/${slug}`}>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for pointing that out. I must have missed it.